# Fetching data from Key Value JSON object

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON object below, but i'm struggling to get name, value from it.

I would want to get the values and save them into a database.

```
$json = '
{
  "Body":
  {
    "stkCallback":
    {
      "ResultCode":0,
      "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
      "CallbackMetadata":
      {
        "Item":
        [
          {
            "Name":"Amount",
            "Value":10
          },
          {
            "Name":"TransactionDate",
            "Value":20170727154800
          },
          {
            "Name":"PhoneNumber",
            "Value":26721566839
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}';
```

How can I get the "Name":"Amount" values and "Name":"TransactionDate" value.

At least for the rest

```
$ResultCode = json_decode($json)->Body->stkCallback->ResultCode;
$ResultDesc = json_decode($json)->Body->stkCallback->ResultDesc;
```

The question is, how do I get the values in a loop when some have values and others don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$response=json_decode($json,true);

echo $amount=$response['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item']['0']['Value'];
echo $TransactionDate=$response['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item']['1']['Value'];
echo $PhoneNumber=$response['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item']['2']['Value'];
```

You have all the values in variables now.

Comment: Can I avoid the use of indexes in array?

Comment: Yes, you can, in this case you have to use foreach and then store the name and value of array(foreach loop) as key-val in a new array.
If you don't want to use this array mechanism then indexes can't be replaced...